# viewport to make site fit window, all phones

Tags: html, css, mobile, viewport

I'm having a hard time finding the right viewport that works for all phones. What I'm trying to do here is that my regular website (not mobile) to scale to fit the window without having to pinch zoom out. Any ideas on viewports?

My current is.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

This will work on iPhone.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Answer (score 0):

How is your website's layout? do you have a specific width for your content (like apple.com)?
if so, use it in your viewport meta tag.
if your website is flexible, like amazon.com for example, use `content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"` and give body `width:100%;`. you can do that with a media query if you don't want to affect your desktop version. (http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/)